# Why my conditions dont work inside for loop?

Tags: python, loops

The task is to take the amount of stars from the user and then print it as a reverse pyramid.

The number must be odd and from 0 to 11. It always prints 11 stars and ignores the conditions no matter what given

```
stars = int(input("Put the odd number of stars\n"))
space = 0
for stars in range(11, 0, -2):
    if stars > 11 and stars < 1 and (stars % 2 != 0):
        print("wrong number")
print(space * " " + stars * '*')
space = space + 1
print("")
```

Comment: How can stars be greater than 11 and less than 1 at the same time?

Comment: You're replacing the user's input with the values from `range()`.

Comment: if its smaller than 1 it should print "the wrong number"

Comment: It's already guaranteed to be `in range(11, 0`, so why check it?

Comment: But you have `and`, which means it has to satisfy both conditions at the same time.

Comment: Ok so I fixed that with "or". Now it prints "wrong number" 6 times

Comment: Seems to me, your "wrong number" output should be after the input, not within a loop... But yes stars % 2 != 0 is true several times in the range of 1,11

Answer (score 1):

Your test shouldn't be in the loop, it should be right after the input. And you need to use `or`, not `and`, so it will succeed if either check is true. And to prohibit an even number, the modulus test should be `== 0`.

Then you need to use a different variable for the input than the loop iteration variable, and use the input number as the starting point in the `range()` function rather than hard-coding 11.

```
while True:
    number = int(input("Put the odd number of stars\n"))
    if number > 11 or number < 1 or (number % 2 == 0):
        print("wrong number")
    else:
        break

space = 0
for stars in range(number, 0, -2):
    print(space * " " + stars * '*')
    space = space + 1
```

Comment: Minor adjustment: `for space, star in enumerate(range`

Comment: Thank you so much <3 What in your opinion is the core of my problem? I've just started

Comment: Not thinking about the problem clearly. This is the root of most beginner programming errors.

Comment: It's also common to misunderstand boolean operators, because the words aren't used the same way in English.